# Prove that $|x|$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Show how $f(x) = |x|$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Use the fact that $| |x| - |y| | \leq |x-y|$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I do believe that's a complete answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, and take arbitrary $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Choose $\delta = \epsilon $. Hence, if

$$ |x - y| \leq \delta \implies | |x| - |y| | \leq |x -y | \leq \delta = \epsilon $$.

So, by definition $x \to |x| $ is uniformly continuous on the real line. Notice the inequality above follows from the reversed triangle inequality which is in fact an application of the famous triangle inequality applied to

$ x = x + y - y $ and $y = y + x - x $

and a little bit of playing.

Comment: downvoter explain what is wrong with this answer